# How does iPhone discover an external accessory via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, external-accessory

How does an iPhone know to connect to an MFi device via Bluetooth automatically? Is the Bluetooth on iPhone constantly looking for a device to hook up to? What happens if there are a few MFi (all with Bluetooth support) around?

Answer (score 0):

You import **ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h** in your .m file(implementation) so that you can use the libraries that contains the accessory information or get available accessories around. Using this, we can also open a session with the selected accessory.

I'm not sure if you can connect to multiple bluetooth devices that are detected.

Answer (score 0):

The user must go to Settings/Bluetooth or Settings/General/Bluetooth (according to which version of iOS the device runs), and wait till the MFi accessory got discovered by the iOS.

Then the user must manually connect the device for the first time. The accessory usually remembers the pairing relationship and reconnect to the iOS automatically, if the user got so lucky when the bluetooth of iOS is on.

Though I have never tried to played with connection of multiple bluetooth MFi devices, Apple's documents suggested that after iOS 5, it is supported.